# Visual Studio 2010 disable absolute namespace reference on autocomplete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I'm coding in Visual Studio 2010, say that I have some interface:

```
Namespace Some.Huge.Terrible.Namespace.Adhering.To.Company.Standards
    Public Interface MyInterface
        ...
        Property SomeThing as String
        ...
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

And a class:

```
Public Class CoolThings
    Implements MyInterface
```

When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `MyInterface`, Visual Studio will put

`Property SomeThing as String Implements Some.Huge.Terrible.Namespace.Adhering.To.Company.Standards.MyInterface.SomeThing`

I would like it to, instead, simply put:

`Property SomeThing as String Implements MyInterface.SomeThing`

It does the same thing for all methods, etc. that I have to implement and it's mildly annoying to either have to look at a stupidly long reference, or clean it all up since I'm importing the namespace at the top of my class anyway.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio that I can use to switch that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no there is nothing you can do here to prevent this.  This is a limitation of the Vb.Net IDE and something the team is definitely aware of.

I did a quick search on connect and couldn't find an existing issue for this feature.  It's generally referred to as "minimally qualified name".  I encourage you to file a connect bug on this

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio